# Scrollview using Remoteview

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to use a  < HorizontalScrollView >  for a notification that uses RemoteView. I understand that RemoteView does not allow this. However, I've seen apps that work around this and need to know if this can be accomplished using < merge > in layouts. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you know an app that does that? we can see how is it doing this